# Issues related to send email using Pear and SMTP: Failed to connect socket: fsockopen

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, pear

I have a server and trying to send email using Pear and SMTP. Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);
ini_set("include_path", '/home/example/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
require_once "Mail.php";
$host = "ssl://mail.example.com";
$username = "info@example.com";
$password = "ABC@123";
$port = "465";
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$email_from = "info@example.com";
$email_subject = "Subject Line Here: " ;
$email_body = "whatever you like" ;
$email_address = "noreply@example.com";


$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Pear Library are installed and path is correct. But when I run the code. Getting this error:

> Failed to connect to ssl://mail.example.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to
>   connect socket: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://mail.example.com:465 (Unknown error) (code: -1, response: )]

Don't know where is the issue. openssl_dl is enable. Port is also open at TCP_IN. Is any issue with the ssl. Is it requred to install on my domain name or hostname. If yes then please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Did you find an answer for your problem? If so, please post it here. I am also facing the same issue. I couldn't find the answer